# How to add files from S3 bucket to output artifacts in AWS CodePipeline? (NodeJS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, buildspec

I am using a AWS CodePipeline which fetches the source from my git repository, uses `CodeBuild` buildSpec to build and save output artifacts to S3 bucket, which ultimately gets deployed to `Elastic BeanStalk` (NodeJS Environment).

Everything works fine but I require the pipeline to copy 1 particular file from one of my `AWS S3` buckets and add it to the `output artifacts` before deploying it to the `EB`

Can it be done using the buildSpec?

```
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
    # - How to add a file from S3 to the artifacts?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation is as part of the `build` or `post_build`, copy the required file from s3 into your build directory.

```
build:
  commands:
    - echo "Build commands"
    - aws s3 cp --region=xx-xxxx-x "s3://file/in/s3" "local-file-instance-to-include"
```

Then you will have the file copied from s3, available for your build, and you can add it to the artifacts output.

Comment: Tried adding the above command and now I am getting this error: `COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: aws s3 cp ...... Reason: exit status 1`

Comment: The issue was with the permissions. The CB role didn't have permission to access S3 buckets. Thanks.

Comment: Worked perfectly, but since I am loading a private key, I don't want to leave the bucket open to the public, do you know how to apply policies in this approach?